# Access JavaScript variables in scope in which object was created

Tags: javascript, scope, this

When an object is created using the `new` keyword, is there any way to access variables in the scope in which it was created, other than by passing in the invocation context (`this`).

For example, if I have:

```
var parent = function() {
    this.parent_property = "Property set on parent object";
    this.kid = new child();
};

var child = function() {
    this.childMethod = function(){
        //how to return parent property
    }
};

var test = new parent();
console.log(test.kid.childMethod());
```

How can I access `parent_property` from  `childMethod`? The only solution I can see is passing `this` to the `child`'s  is constructor, like this:

```
var parent = function() {
    this.parent_property = "Property set on parent object";
    this.kid = new child(this);
};

var child = function(parent) {
    var parent = parent;
    this.childMethod = function(){
        return parent.parent_property;
        //how to return parent property
    }
};

var test = new parent();
console.log(test.kid.childMethod());
```

Are there any other ways of doing this? And is there any downside/pitfalls doing it this way?

Comment: _"The only solution I can see is passing this to the child's is constructor"_ <- sounds good. What's the problem?

Comment: @Phil No problem, I just want to know what available options there are to solve this problem and what the relative advantages and disadvantages of each are. I want to get a deeper understanding so that I can apply the ideas to different problem as they arrise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, there is no parent, or child:

```
var Child = function() {
    this.childMethod = function(){
        // how to return parent property
    }
};
```

This is just a constructor function that you may call from another constructor function, but there is no [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) there and, so far, there is no instance.

There is nothing wrong with your current approach but you may have an incorrect understanding of [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance) in JavaScript

This is the example from MDN

```
function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.interests = interests;
};

Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name.first + '.');
};
```

You add a method to the `Person` constructor's prototype so that every instance of Person will instantly inherit the `greeting()` method.

Comment: Thanks. Your statement that _so far, there is no instance_ and showing my child constructor in isolation was key in helping me understand this. I can see now that whilst my example has a hierarchy, that hierarchy is one of composition not inheritance; the parent is composed of a child object. Under composition the child object has no knowledge of its parent, unless its explicitly told about it, as I have done in my second example.